# Get Ref of dynamic component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a component like this

```
const mapping = {
    'a': <span>AAA</span>,
    'b': <span>BBB</span>,
};

class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                {mapping[this.props.key]}
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

And I'm interested whether it's possible to get ref of the result element of `{mapping[this.props.key]}`

Are there any ways of doing this? I have only few ideas with creating additional wrappers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would try something like 
```
const mapping = (key, getRef) => ({
    'a': <span ref={getRef}>AAA</span>,
}[key]);
```

Comment: @givehug Yeah, this can do the trick, but if the mapping is huge then this object will be created every time we call the function which is not good, I guess

Comment: how about: `const mapping = { 'a': setRef => <span ref={setRef}>AAA</span>};` then `mapping[this.props.key](this.setRef)`

Comment: Hm.. looks nice.

For now I ended up using simple switch-case like

    `getIcon = (key, saveRef) => {
        switch(key) {
             case 'a': return <span ref={setRef}>AAA<span/>
        }
    }`

But maybe I'll give your approach a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider both of these approaches as a correct answer:

#### 1: Use switch case to get the correct component and provide it with ref function

```
getIcon = (key, saveRef) => { 
    switch(key) {
        case 'a': return <span ref={setRef}>AAA<span/>
    }
}
```

#### 2: @givehug 's approach to keep mapping's values as functions which accept save ref function and return the component

`const mapping = {
    'a': setRef => <span ref={setRef}>AAA</span>
};
mapping[this.props.key](this.setRef)`